# Structure of Mat in opencv?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, mat

I tried **Structure of Mat** my app shows as "Run failed". Anyother way to do this?

The below is the code I tried and its getting failed. How to make this workout or anyother ways are there?

**"Common.h"**

```
struct initialize {
      cv :: Mat G_Sm;
};
```

**"Initialize.cpp"**

```
struct initialize* initfunction ( ) {
    struct initialize* initializemat = ( initialize* ) malloc(sizeof(*initializemat));
    initializemat -> G_Sm = Mat:: zeros ( 3,1, CV_8U );
    return (initializemat);
}
```

**"main.cpp"**

```
int main () { 
   struct initialize* initializem = initfunction ();
   cout << initializem -> G_Sm << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Instead of Mat if I use "int" the program is not getting crashed. If it is "Mat" variable in the structure the program gets crashed.

Comment: Is `Mat` a pointer type?

Comment: You are using `cout` on unintialized `cv::Mat`.

Comment: @sgar91 even if I comment out cout its the same result.

Comment: @DanielFischer Mat is not a pointer

Comment: @sgar91 I have edited my codeadded one more line in my code..

Comment: Well this is strange. The program is running perfect on my PC. Its displaying an empty matrix. May be its an issue of incorrect library being linked.

Comment: @sgar91 Undefined behaviour is undefined. It may seem to do what you intended, but it's still not a valid program.

Comment: @sgar91 molbdnilo's answer solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use C++ instead of C:

```
initialize* initfunction ( ) {
    initialize* initializemat = new initialize;
    return initializemat;
}
```

You shouldn't allocate C++ objects with `malloc`.
`malloc` doesn't call any constructors for you, leaving `G_Sm` uninitialised.

Comment: Or just build it on the stack.

Comment: @juanchopanza Of course, but I wanted to keep the interface intact.